# Why doesn't my Makefile put my object files into the /build folder?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile that looks like this:

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c11
BUILD_DIR = ./build
SRC := ${wildcard src/*.c}
OBJ := ${SRC:.c=.o}

${BUILD_DIR}/main: ${OBJ} 
    ${CC} $^ -o $@

${BUILD_DIR}/%.o: %.c
    ${CC} -c $< -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f ${BUILD_DIR}/*
```

When I run this makefile, my object files go into the src/ folder. However, I thought that when I specified ${BUILD_DIR}/%.o, and then $@, it would cause my .o files to go into the BUILD_DIR?

Comment: `${BUILD_DIR}/main: ${OBJ}`. That says that `main` depends on `.o` files in `src`. You need to prepend each of the dependencies with the build directory.

Comment: Changing that line to ${BUILD_DIR}/main: ${BUILD_DIR}/${OBJ} gives me an error when running Make: "unable to open output file 'build/src/main.o': 'No such file or directory'"

Comment: Yeah, `${OBJ}` is a list of all the objects. You need to replace `src` with the build directory for each individual object. Something like: `OBJ := $(patsubst src/%.c, ${BUILD_DIR}/%.o, ${SRC})`

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Many thanks, Kaylum. That did the trick.